# Why does my EF Core migration ignore the model's OnDelete settings?

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-core, .net-core

I have the following code in an, what looks like a futile, attempt to configure the `OnDelete` behaviour for foreign keys:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

    modelBuilder.Entity<Contact>()
        .HasOne(e => e.Gender)
        .WithMany()
        .HasForeignKey(e => e.GenderId)
        .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Restrict);

    modelBuilder.Entity<Contact>()
        .HasOne(e => e.Title)
        .WithMany()
        .HasForeignKey(e => e.TitleId)
        .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Restrict);
}
```

Yet when I generate the first migration, that creates this and another two tables, it creates constraints for `Contact` as follows:

```
constraints: table =>
{
    table.PrimaryKey("PK_Contact", x => x.Id);
    table.ForeignKey(
        name: "FK_Contact_Gender_GenderId",
        column: x => x.GenderId,
        principalTable: "Gender",
        principalColumn: "Id",
        onDelete: ReferentialAction.SetNull);
    table.ForeignKey(
        name: "FK_Contact_Title_TitleId",
        column: x => x.TitleId,
        principalTable: "Title",
        principalColumn: "Id",
        onDelete: ReferentialAction.Cascade);
});
```

Where the blazes does it get `SetNull`, on a non-nullable column, `GenderId`? `Cascade` is maybe a default, having ignored my configuration.

Comment: Looks like a bug. Could you [submit a new issue](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework/issues/new)?

Comment: @IvanStoev Pray tell why it doesn't apply to EF Core?  What are the `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.*` packages I'm using if not EF Core?

Comment: What about your issue, you might consider @bricelam suggestion, since I wasn't able to reproduce it with EF Core / Full .NET Framework.

Comment: I have submitted an issue, and the devil himself is handling it: Ref No. #6668

Comment: @IvanStoev Yes, sorry, I suspected it was unrelated just after I replied.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested by @bricelam, I submitted an issue and got a correct response in less than 24 hours. Microsoft's Smit Patel advised:

> In your `project.json` you have reference to
>   `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Commands` which was deprecated a while
>   ago and should be removed.

I removed it and the re-generated migration now has the correct `onDelete` values for both FKs.